# XwcLookupString cause progress crash when switch Input Method or restart Input Method

Tags: x11, xlib

Based on the debian operating system, when using the **XwcLookupString** function provided by Xlib, if the input method is switched or restarted when the window is opened to input text, the XwcLookupString function will cause the process to crash and there will be no core cump info

1. I already know that XwcLookupString needs an **input context** parameter, and after restarting the input method, the input context parameter becomes invalid;
2. after I add parameter checking before calling XwcLoopupString, it still crashes occasionally, but the frequency is greatly reduced. It seems that the input method startup time is not fixed. sometimes After the input event of my window is generated and the context is re-initialized, the input method starts up. At this time, the XwcLoopupString call will still crash.

How can I completely avoid the crash?